# PostGis: Add new geometry column & insert into it newly created polygon - violates check constraint enforce_srid

Tags: postgis

I added a new column by:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('table_name', 'column_name', 4326, 'POLYGON', 2, false);
```

Which means 2D polygon in WGS84.

Then I inserted a new polygon into specific row by:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(lon1 lat1, lon2 lat2 ... lon1 lat1)'))
WHERE gid=26;
```

The result is "violates check constraint enforce_srid" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't specify the SRID parameter in `ST_GeomFromText`, which is basically what the error message said.

Comment: Where I need to specify? In the new column I wrote the 4326

Comment: Look at the documentation.  You need to specify an SRID in every `ST_GeomFromText` or it will use `0`, which violates the constraint.  Do you realize you're wasting time by generating a line from WKT then converting to polygon when you could just generate a polygon in one step?

Comment: How can I generate polygon in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a geometry colum with SRID 4326 but then you are trying to put in a polygon that does not identify an SRID.  You just need to pass the polygon to ST_SetSRID() like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(lon1 lat1, lon2 lat2 ... lon1 lat1)')),4326)
WHERE gid=26;
```